# SAS, convert Date to number

Tags: sas

I have a column of dates. For example 08/2000 with date format. How do I convert them into numeric form 082000? I follow some guideline on internet but it is not correct.

```
ASOFDT_temp=datepart(ASOFDT);
ASOFDT_Num=putn( ASOFDT_temp,'yymmn6.');
```

Comment: '08/2000' doesn't look like a date to me. Looks like a character variable.  Also why store it a number with the month before the year?  If you really want to store it in a number then use digits like YYYYMM or YYYYMMDD so that you won't have issues with leading zeros or sorting.

Comment: Than you, Tom. I check it again. Its type is date. I will take your advise to change it to YYYYMM, but if you have time, could you explain to me what potential issues will caused by leading zeros?

Comment: Tom, thank you. I have already see the problem. See my reply to Joe below :)

Comment: If the type is DATE then you can use a date format on it.  `INPUT(PUT(asofdt,YYMMn6.),6.)` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One good way is to use VVALUE, if they already have a format.  `vvalue` takes the formatted value of a variable.

```
  ASOFDT_num = input(compress(vvalue(ASOFDT),'/'),6.);
```

`compress` removes the slash, and `input` makes it a number.  `putn` won't work as it makes a character variable (`input` -> number, `put` -> character, almost always).

Comment: Joe, your code works. Is it possible to switch the year and date to make the number as YYYYMM? As Tom mentioned in his reply, leading 0 caused problem. 012000 recorded as 12000. Anyway to change it to 200001?

Comment: Sure, either reformat the date var to be yyyymmn6. Or use substr.

Comment: Thank you. I did it in a awkward way but I get what I want,

Comment: month1 = substr(compress(vvalue(ASOFDT),'/'),1,2);
   year1 = substr(compress(vvalue(ASOFDT),'/'),3,4);
   ASOFDT_num= cats(of year1 month1)*1;

Answer (score 0):

If the original field is really a DATE then you can convert it in place since it is already a numeric field.

You could do it using PUT and INPUT function calls.

```
asofdt = INPUT(PUT(asofdt,YYMMn6.),6.);
```

Or you could use a little arithmetic.

```
asofdt = year(asofdt)*100 + month(asofdt);
```

Remember to clear the date format from the variable that is making it look like '08/2000' by using a FORMAT statement.

```
format asofdt ;
```